# How can I get my input tags on my form to list above each other?And connect to my PHP page?

Tags: php

```
 How can I get my input tags on my form to list above each other?And connect to my PHP
```

page? I have tried to put them in a list but no luck, is there a way I can get them to list

without a li tag?And is action---my page the correct way to connect the PHP? And if so how

would I then connect  my Thank you page to the submit button?

Thanks........................................................................................................................................................................................

```
       <div id="container">

    <fieldset id="contact_form">
                       <form id="cform" name="cform" method="post" action="process.php">

              <input type="text" id="name" name="name" value="Full Name*" onfocus="if(this.value == 'Full Name*') this.value = ''"
                                onblur="if(this.value == '') this.value = 'Full Name*'" style="position: relative"/> 
              <input type="text" id="email" name="email" value="Email Address*" onfocus="if(this.value == 'Email Address*') this.value = ''"
                                onblur="if(this.value == '') this.value = 'Email Address*'" style="position: relative"/> 
               <input type="text" id="subject" name="subject" value="Subject*" onfocus="if(this.value == 'Subject*') this.value = ''"
                                onblur="if(this.value == '') this.value = 'Subject*'" style="position: relative"/> 
             <textarea id="msg" name="message" onfocus="if(this.value == 'Your Message*') this.value = ''"
                                onblur="if(this.value == '') this.value = 'Your Message*'"style="position: relative">Your Message*</textarea> 
               <button id="submit" class="button" action="thanks.html"style="position: relative"> Send Message</button> 

              </form>
            </fieldset>
    </div

    Here is the css...  

      input {
        border: 5px solid white; 
        -webkit-box-shadow: 
          inset 0 0 8px  rgba(0,0,0,0.1),
                0 0 16px rgba(0,0,0,0.1); 
        -moz-box-shadow: 
          inset 0 0 8px  rgba(0,0,0,0.1),
                0 0 16px rgba(0,0,0,0.1); 
        box-shadow: 
          inset 0 0 8px  rgba(0,0,0,0.1),
                0 0 16px rgba(0,0,0,0.1); 
        padding: 15px;
        background: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
        margin: 0 0 10px 0;
    }




     #contact_form input{
     background:#ffffff;
     position:list-style: 5;}

    fieldset#contact_form 
    {width:100%;
    float:left;
    height:100%;}




    #submit{ border: 5px solid white; 
        -webkit-box-shadow: 
          inset 0 0 8px  rgba(0,0,0,0.1),
                0 0 16px rgba(0,0,0,0.1); 
        -moz-box-shadow: 
          inset 0 0 8px  rgba(0,0,0,0.1),
                0 0 16px rgba(0,0,0,0.1); 
        box-shadow: 
          inset 0 0 8px  rgba(0,0,0,0.1),
                0 0 16px rgba(0,0,0,0.1); 
        padding: 15px;
        background:#ffffff;
        margin: 0 0 10px 0;}


    fieldset#contact_form textarea{width:60.0%;
    background:#ffffff;
    height:150px;
        border: 5px solid white; 
        -webkit-box-shadow: 
          inset 0 0 8px  rgba(0,0,0,0.1),
                0 0 16px rgba(0,0,0,0.1); 
        -moz-box-shadow: 
          inset 0 0 8px  rgba(0,0,0,0.1),
                0 0 16px rgba(0,0,0,0.1); 
        box-shadow: 
          inset 0 0 8px  rgba(0,0,0,0.1),
                0 0 16px rgba(0,0,0,0.1); 
        padding: 15px;
        background:#ffffff;
        margin: 0 0 10px 0;}

`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply add a `<br />` after each form element to make them list. For example:

```
<input type="text" id="name" name="name" value="Full Name*" ...  /><br />
```

According to your code when you click submit the process.php file will execute and not thanks.html.

```
<form id="cform" name="cform" method="post" action="process.php">
```

If you want to show a thanks message you should add that code inside process.php.

Or you can do a redirect:

```
header( 'Location: http://www.yoursite.com/thanks.html' ) ;
```

Comment: Thank you that worked great!But if I change the action how will I link my Html to my php page?Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Either place then in the rows of a table or in stacking divs contained inside a wrapping div.